# Docker. No such file or directory

Tags: python, linux, docker, command-line-interface, boot2docker

I have some files which I want to move them to a docker container.
But at the end docker can't find a file..

The folder with the files on local machine are at **/home/katalonne/flask4**

**File Structure** if it matters:

[image: File Structure if it matters]
The **Dockerfile**:

```
#
# First Flask App Dockerfile
#
#

# Pull base image.
FROM centos:7.0.1406

# Build commands
RUN yum install -y python-setuptools mysql-connector mysql-devel gcc python-devel
RUN easy_install pip
RUN mkdir /opt/flask4
WORKDIR /opt/flask4
ADD requirements.txt /opt/flask4
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /opt/flask4

# Define deafult command.
CMD ["python","hello.py"]

# Expose ports.
EXPOSE 5000
```

So I built the image with this command :

```
docker build -t flask4 .
```

I ran the container with volume by :

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 -v /home/Katalonne/flask4:/opt/flask4 --name web flask4
```

---

And when I want to run the file on the container :

```
docker logs -f web
```

I get this error that it can not find my hello.py file :

```
python: can't open file 'hello.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

What is my fault?

P.S. : I'm a Docker and Linux partially-noob.

Answer (score 6):

The files and directories that are located in the same location as your Dockerfile are indeed available (temporarily) to your docker build.  But, after the docker build, unless you have used `ADD` or `COPY` to move those files permanently to the docker container, they will not be available to your docker container after the build is done.  This file context is for the build, but you want to move them to the container.

You can add the following command:

```
...
ADD . /opt/flask4
ADD . . 

# Define deafult command.
CMD ["python","hello.py"]
```

The line    `ADD . .` should copy over all the things in your temporary build context to the container.  The location that these files will go to is where your `WORKDIR` is pointing to (/opt/flask4).

If you only wanted to add hello.py to your container, then use

```
ADD hello.py hello.py
```

So, when you run `CMD ["python","hello.py"]`, the `pwd` that you will be in is `/opt/flask4`, and hello.py should be in there, and running the command `python hello.py` in that directory should work.

HTH.

Comment: I'm nearly done but how can I delete the last container or update the container?

'docker run -d -p 5000:5000 -v /home/Katalonne/flask4:/opt/flask4 --name web flask4' ?

Comment: `docker rm web` to remove the container.  `docker rmi flask4` to remove the image.

Comment: hm... it gives me the same error unfortunately...
it can't find the file hello.py ...

Comment: Let me verify: You deleted your old container and the old image, you added the line `ADD . .` right above the `CMD` in your dockerfile, you ran `docker build .`, it created a new image, you created a new container based on that image by using `docker run -d -p 5000:5000 -v /home/Katalonne/flask4:/opt/flask4 --name web flask4`, and you had the same error?  Just from your last comment, wanted to make sure that we were on the same page... I did this locally, and it worked fine for me.

Comment: I did Include `ADD . .` above `CMD`
then  I did : `docker build -t flask4 .`
and then : `docker run -d -p 5000:5000 -v /home/Katalonne/flask4:/opt/flask4 --name web flask4`


 | Hey do you have skype or anything, just want to chat with you about docker...

Comment: Try `docker run -d -p 5000:5000 -v /home/Katalonne/flask4:/opt/flask4 --name web flask bash`, which will put you inside of the container.  Then, run a `ls` command, as well as `python hello.py`.  What are the results?  I don't have Skype.