# I have python script copied in dockerfile for base image , how can i run that python code in ci.yml file

Tags: python, docker, gitlab-ci

this is my base image  docker file
which is installing python and some basic requirements . also copying my script verification.py

now in second part there is a gitlab.ciyml file which is using that builded image as base image to build other images,
i need to run that python script before building other images .
but

it is giving me  error here

```
python3: can't open file 'publication_verification.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

```bash
FROM docker:19.03.1

ADD requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app/

RUN apk add --update --no-cache python3=3.7.10-r0   && ln -sf python3 /usr/bin/python
RUN python3 -m ensurepip
RUN pip3 install --no-cache --upgrade pip setuptools
RUN python3 --version
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .pynacl_deps build-base python3-dev libffi-dev
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
COPY verification.py ./
CMD [ "python3  ", "./verification.py"]
```

```yaml
.build-img-temp: &build-img-template
  tags:
    - dockerfile-builder
  image:base:0.1
  stage: build-image
  services:
    - docker:19.03.1-dind

  before_script:
    - docker info

build-publication-verification:
  <<: *build-img-template
 
  script:
    - python3 --version
    - python3  verification.py
```

Comment: in the code it´s called `verification.py` but in the error it's called `publication_verification.py`, is that the problem?

Comment: no thats not thr issue , i changed the name to verification.py   while asking the question\

Comment: what's your folder structure? the error is saying it can't find the file

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36022051/docker-no-such-file-or-directory) helps? (nb I just googled the error + python docker)